# Expiry Policy on Off Heap entries not working as expected in Ignite

Tags: ignite, distributed-system

Expiry policy on off-heap entries is not working as expected. I am seeing a linear increase in off-heap entries and after some time sudden dip in off-heap size. Is only marking of cache entry done after expiry time and collected later in bulk? I am not finding any documentation regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

We need to enable eager TTL in the cache configuration. It will create a thread in the background and removes the expired entries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two modes of expiry policy in Ignite: eager and non-eager: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/expiry-policies#eager-ttl

In case of an eager TTL entries are expired periodically by a background thread. When a non-eager TTL is used, then entries are only expired upon access. So, it's possible for expired entries to be stored in off-heap for some time until they get read.

Also keep in mind that JVM can allocate more memory than is immediately required. The amount of memory allocated by the Java process is not directly related to the amount of data stored in Ignite.